# Bulk uploading data in Google App Engine - problem

Tags: python, google-app-engine

I am trying to upload some data to GAE using the bulk uploader outlined;
http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/tools/uploadingdata.html

When I run the command;

```
appcfg.py create_bulkloader_config --filename=bulkloader.yaml
```

I get:

```
appcfg.py: error: Expected either --url or a single <directory> argument.
```

From looking around, a few other people have had the same problem but the suggestions given to fix the issue do not seem to work.

Any help will be much appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You must specify the application folder. If you are in it, just run:

```
appcfg.py create_bulkloader_config --filename=bulkloader.yaml .
```

otherwise run:

```
appcfg.py create_bulkloader_config --filename=bulkloader.yaml
path/to/root/gae/app/
```

Comment: The first way of doing it just doesn't work, the second way worked well. Thank you.

Comment: @Shane The first one will work if you actually are in the app's directory.

Comment: second one works. even though I am in the app directory, I get the error appcfg.py [options] create_bulkload_config <directory>

appcfg.py: error: Expected either --url or a single <directory> argument.

Answer (score 0):

There are plenty of steps in the process. After spending much time on something so elementary, I wrote a tutorial to get people through the process quickly and without any fuss.

http://heliodorj.blogspot.com/2011/09/google-app-engine-bulk-download-and.html